# Netbeans on Mac won't create new projects

Tags: macos, java, netbeans

I'm new here and I gotta problem, I need Netbeans for school, I already installed and ran it, but when I try to create a new file or project I get no response nor warning messages from Netbeans, if anyone could help me find a solution I'd be grateful, I'll leave a screenshot for you to see how I see Netbeans.

P.D.: My java version is Java 8 Build 191

[image: Java Version & Build]

[image: Netbeans as I see it]

[image: Java runtime environment settings]

EDIT: I want to create new files and projects, there's also no error message when I click 'New File' or 'New Project', nothing at all happens

Comment: OP, what is your issue exactly? Do you _want_ error messages when you create new files? Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Looks like you have a whole lot of nothing. I could try setting up NetBeans on my Mac tomorrow. In the meantime, have you tried IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse?

Comment: It looks like NetBeans is trying to use a version of Java that is invalid... [1] Locate the file **netbeans.conf** within the **etc** directory under your NetBeans installation directory. [2] It is a text file containing name/value properties. Open it in any text editor. [3] Locate the line containing the property `netbeans_jdkhome`. What is the complete content of that line?